# c# Generics problem

Tags: c#, generics

Can anyone tell me why this does not work?  I would have thought the constraint would make it valid.

```
public class ClassA<T> where T : ICommon
{
    public ClassA()
    {
        ClassB b = new ClassB();
        IEnumerable<T> alist = new List<T>;
        b.Items = alist; 
        //Error: cannot convert from IEnumerable<T> to IEnumerable<ICommon>'
    }

}


public class ClassB
{
    public IEnumerable<ICommon> Items { get; set;}
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This will work in C# 4 with a tweak, but not in C# 3. What you're looking for is *generic variance*, which has been supported in the CLR since .NET 2.0, but not in C# until v4.

Even in C# 4, you need to *also* constrain T to be a reference type - as covariance doesn't work over value types. For example, `List<int>` can't be converted to `IEnumerable<IComparable>` even though `int` implements `IComparable`.

Having tweaked your code a bit (there were a few typos, effectively), this compiles with the C# 4 compiler:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

public interface ICommon {}

// Note the "class" part of the constraint
public class ClassA<T> where T : class, ICommon
{
    public ClassA()
    {
        ClassB b = new ClassB();
        IEnumerable<T> alist = new List<T>();
        b.Items = alist; 
    }   
}

public class ClassB
{
    public IEnumerable<ICommon> Items { get; set;}
}
```

If you're stuck in C# 3 and .NET 3.5, an alternative would be to use `Cast<T>()`:

```
b.Items = alist.Cast<ICommon>();
```

Comment: Interesting, thanks!  (And my scrappy code now tidied up, sir ;) - embarrassingly sloppy without intellisense!)

Answer (score 3):

This is called covariance (or contra? I'm not sure), and is working only in C# 4.0.
You cannot cast `IEnumerable<Common>` to `IEnumerable<ICommon>`. (when Common implements ICommon.)

Try using

```
b.items = from f in alist select (T)f;
```